# Javascript Security

Tags: javascript, security

Over the last few years I've been playing with javascript libraries ranging from [Raphael.js](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) to [D3](https://d3js.org/), I've manipulated animations from all over the web for my own education. I've downloaded js script from various git repositories like [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and much well less known ones.

Recently I started cleaning up my files, getting rid of old experiments and cleaning up some of the files I want to keep. I had a thought about security.

Is there a developer tool that allows me to see what websites I'm communicating with from my JS? Make sure I'm not running someone else's twitter bot or something?

Comment: Network panel of Chrome dev tools

Comment: https://snyk.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most web browsers have some kind of "Network" tab in their development tools. That tab will show you all network activity which is initiated by the currently displayed document:
[image: Firefox network tab]
Clicking on an entry shows you more information. You can, for example, check the stack trace of an XHR request to see which script is responsible for the request.

Comment: Much appreciated. As a quick example, if i reference a js script CDN, i see the GET request for it on my network summary. If within that external CDN script there is further interaction with other sites, should i also see that indirect interaction broken down on this list?

Comment: @DVCITIS yes. Any request made while the page is open will show up there. Say, if you have a web page that sends a request to the server every 10 seconds (e.g., checking for updates), you will see a request every 10 seconds.